# Qt for Android on Mac or Linux build "Can not detect ndk toolchain..."

Tags: linux, macos, qt, android-ndk

I have just installed `SDK`, `NDK`, `JDK`. 
When I type in Terminal:

> **moroz@moroz:~/qt/qt5$** `./configure -developer-build -opensource -confirm-license -xplatform android-g++ -nomake tests -nomake examples -android-ndk android-ndk-r9/ -android-sdk android-sdk-linux/ -android-ndk-host linux-x86_64 -android-toolchain-version 4.8 -skip qttranslations -skip qtwebkit -skip qtserialport -skip qtwebkit-examples`

Then

> **moroz@moroz:~/qt/qt5$** `/home/moroz/qt/qt5/qtbase/configure -top-level -developer-build -opensource -confirm-license -xplatform android-g++ -nomake tests -nomake examples -android-ndk android-ndk-r9/ -android-sdk android-sdk-linux/ -android-ndk-host linux-x86_64 -android-toolchain-version 4.8 -skip qttranslations -skip qtwebkit -skip qtserialport -skip qtwebkit-examples`

I got the follwoing error:

> `Can not detect Android NDK toolchain. Please use -android-toolchain-version to specify`

And there is the same message on Mac and Ubuntu!

Comment: Just because you don't seem to like the perspective of compiling Qt by yourself, if you can develop on Ubuntu and that Qt5.1 is ok for you, just download the official sdk installer. You will just need to install and configure your environment. [http://qt-project.org/downloads](http://qt-project.org/downloads)

Comment: There is no SDK. With the new QT you must build it by yourself(

Comment: my ./configure script does not have a -android-toolchain-version option. Where did you think it has? I am checking stable/dev from git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on a mac you should use

```
-android-ndk-host darwin-x86_64
```

it resolvs -android-ndk-host in ndkfolder/prebuilt/ (I have darwin-x86_x64, android-arm, android-mips, android-x86, common)

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in i7. It shows processor architecture as i386 (32bit), but hardware as x84_64 (64bit).

```
$ uname -p
i386

$ uname -m
x86_64
```

-m      print the machine hardware name.

-p      print the machine processor architecture name.

One must hack qtbase/configure file to return x86_64

```
 macx-g++-64)
            PLATFORM=macx-g++
            NATIVE_64_ARCH=
            case `uname -p` in
            i386) NATIVE_64_ARCH="x86_64" ;;
            powerpc) NATIVE_64_ARCH="ppc64" ;;
            *)   echo "WARNING: Can't detect CPU architecture for macx-g++-64" ;;
            esac
            if [ ! -z "$NATIVE_64_ARCH" ]; then
                QTCONFIG_CONFIG="$QTCONFIG_CONFIG $NATIVE_64_ARCH"
            fi
            ;;
        esac
```

Another solution is to download 32bit Android NDK and use darwin-x86 as host name.

Answer (score 0):

I my case I specified relative path to ndk - same error, after providing full path, it made its job.

Answer (score 0):

- On Android 5.0 and lower, QSslSocket will use Android system's libssl.so and libcrypto.ssl
- On Android >= 6.0, your app must include it's own libssl.so and libcrypto.ssl
- OpenSSL is not part of Qt installation due to legal restrictions in some countries.
- You must consider enabling/disabling the SSL features based on legal restrictions in the region where your application is available.
- [See the SSL configure options for details about the configurable features](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/opensslsupport.html)
- Do not use pre-built OpenSSL libs you find laying about the Internet.

**1) How to Build OpenSSL On macOS:**

To build OpenSSL Android libs for arm, arm-v7a, and x86 using a **macOS** host, this script works great if you use **Android NDK r10e**:

- https://github.com/esutton/android-openssl

** Copy libs to your Qt app's project folder: **

```
platform/
└── android
    └── lib
        └── openssl
            ├── README.md
            ├── android-openssl-vsts.webloc
            ├── arch-armeabi-v7a
            │   ├── libcrypto.a
            │   ├── libcrypto.so
            │   ├── libssl.a
            │   └── libssl.so
            └── arch-x86
                ├── libcrypto.a
                ├── libcrypto.so
                ├── libssl.a
                └── libssl.so
```

**2) Add to your Qt yourapp.pro project file:**

```
android {
    # Android >= 6.0 requires apps to install their own libcrypto.so and libssl.so
    # https://subsite.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/android-openssl
    equals(ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH, armeabi-v7a) {
        ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS += $$files($${PWD}/platform/android/lib/openssl/arch-armeabi-v7a/*.so)
    }
    equals(ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH, x86)  {
        ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS += $$files($${PWD}/platform/android/lib/openssl/arch-x86/*.so)
    }
}
```

I wasted *so* much time trying to build OpenSLL on Linux and macOS until I found that script, and figured out I needed to build with Android NDK r10e or earlier.

The Qt [Adding OpenSSL Support for Android](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/opensslsupport.html) guide did not work for me.  However it may work ***if I had reverted to NDK r10e***.

I hope this saves someone some time.